# Lenovo Ideapad U310 encrypted w/ PGP WDE can't get to BIOS or boot menu

Tags: windows-7, boot, bios, encryption, lenovo-laptop

The Lenovo U310 Touch with Windows 7 was encrypted using PGP Symantec Encryption Desktop 10.3.2. Everything seemed to work fine until I used a windows 7 repair CD to restore an older system image back to this drive.

Now when the ideapad starts up, I still get a symentec encryption username and passphrase screen. When enter in the username and passphrase, I get past it but I see Windows Boot Manager, Windows failed to start. Statux 0xc000000f and then anything that I do, I get thrown back to the PGP screen, and this error screen.

If I use Fn+f12, or Fn+f2, or Fn+f11, I again and thrown back to the PGP screen.

If I shut the system off, and start it with the novo button, I see a menu that says Normal startup, bios setup, boot menu, system recovery. All 4 options return me back to the PGP Encryption screen, and then back to Windows Failed to start.

How can I get to the BIOS, or sys recovery, or even boot from external CD drive so I can get a clean build of an OS?

So I can't get to the BIOS, I can't get to the OS, and I can't boot from CD. Is there anything left to do than to open up the laptop, and pull out the SSD and wipe it on a different machine?

Comment: Pull the drive, hook it to another computer and format it.

Answer (score 0):

PGP is a nightmare, just get an external keyboard, do a cold boot and use F12 to do a boot menu and wipe it.